# Is a common approach to calibration reasonable?

Tags: calibration

"Model Calibration" article in [Encyclopedia of Quantitative Finance](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-400799.html)  states that

> .  .  .  a common approach for selecting a pricing measure $\mathbb{Q}$ is to choose, given a set of liquidly traded derivatives with (discounted) terminal payoffs $(H^i)_{i \in I}$ and market prices $(C_i)_{i \in I}$, a pricing measure $\mathbb{Q}$ compatible with the observed market prices

where $\mathbb{Q}$ denotes

> a probability measure on the set $\Omega$ of possible trajectories $(S_t)_{ t \in [0,T ]}$ of the underlying asset such that the asset price $\frac{S_t}{N_t}$ discounted by the numeraire $N_t$ is a martingale.

But we know that market prices $(C_i)_{i \in I}$ are generated by fallible human beings!  Each of them has rather limited knowledge about "possible trajectories $(S_t)_{ t \in [0,T ]}$ of the underlying asset". Otherwise they wouldn't need the model we are trying to calibrate, would they?

So **The Calibration Process** receives some prices $(C_i)_{i \in I}$, some  arbitrarily choosen mathematical model (i.e. [Heston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_model)) and produces as an output the calibrated model which supposedly able to give us predictions about the future $(S_t)_{ t \in [0,T ]}$

Why do we believe that **The Calibration Process** is different from [**GIGO**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) process?

Comment: It's an interesting question. Have you read the excellent (IMO): How Derivatives and Risk Models Really Work: Sociological Pricing and the Role of Co-Ordination (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2365294). The idea is that in a perfect world were complex instruments can be perfectly replicated by elementary building blocks like vanilla options (the $C_i$'s), then you need to have the right prices for the latter. Of course, the world is not perfect and additional features need to be priced in, hence the need for a good *model*...

Comment: This also reminds me of the, not less excellent, Blank Swan by Elie Ayache. Calibrating is merely a way to mark a wrong model to the market. And although this will give you an appropriate "static" view (if you calibrate to vanilla options), this does not mean you'll capture the appropriate "dynamics".

Comment: In my opinion, the the answer to your question is simply that it is no different for the exact reasons cited in the comments above.  Excellent sources cited by @Quantuple.

Comment: @Quantuple Thanks. Rebonatto's article is in my reading list since I read  https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/29865/15154.  I got Blank Swan too.

Comment: @amdopt I suspect that it is no different. But having accepted that we can't help but agree that Mathematical Finance is a new branch of Alchemy. It is a frightening conclusion

Comment: Excellent question @Zer0hedge! All my brain can muster right now is "because normality". But that is a poor justification, especially because I know in my heart that the distribution of $\mathbb{E^Q}[S_{i \in I}] \not \to N(\mu_S, \sigma^2_S)$. But then again, the end result of active trading does in fact look a lot like the expectation of a coin toss.

Comment: @quantuple when you say that calibrating is a way to mark a "wrong" model to market, I would say that that is misleading - you're projecting onto the subspace that model can represent. Sure, it's just language, but I think the language you had is exaggerating a point for effect. Further, if you're projecting some space onto a subspace, and then looking at a dimension not accounted for in your subspace (ie projecting onto a non stochastic vol subspace and then pricing an option on vol) then this is not a failing of the model, but of the user (Imo)...

Comment: Another consideration is "what happens when *everybody* starts to use the same model?" you'll see you price everything perfectly (according to the market), but it is just that everybody is wrong. Not sure if this is what you're getting at with your fallible humans point.

Comment: @will I'd rather say that you're projecting my comment onto your own subspace of ideas :) This is not what I meant at all. What I mean is more along the lines of Ayache, i.e. there is some kind of logical fallacy in the way *all* pricing models are built. As for your second point this is indeed the roots of relative pricing (i.e. complete markets + AOA). It is ketchup economics. Oversimplifying: You have 1L of ketchup selling at 5 USD. By replication and AOA you propose a "fair price" of 10 USD for 2L of ketchup. Does that mean that ketchup as a commodity is fairly priced? No.

Comment: @will Ayache @ https://www.wilmott.com/from-within/. What I meant by "wrong" models, is exactly what he means by "smile problem". Teaser: *The smile problem isn’t something that happens to the Black–Scholes–Merton (BSM) model from outside. It is not a falsification of the BSM model. The smile problem isn’t that BSM assumes the underlying price process to be lognormal and that it suddenly happens in reality, externally to BSM, that the process is different, i.e., admitting of stochastic volatility and jumps. The smile problem is produced from* **inside** (play scary music).

Comment: @Quantuple "A model is merely your reflection of reality and, like probability, it describes neither you nor the world, but only a relationship between you and that world."  D. Lindley "The philosophy of statistics"(2000)

Answer (score 4):

I am intrigued by this question because it gets at the heart of so many grey areas of the financial system in which it becomes almost impossible to know how many assets derive their values from some unseen or ill-prescribed, but presumed extant, underlying process.

Calibration can be interpreted as means of deriving an expectation which is the probabilistic point estimate, subject to certain parameters, $p_1,\,p_2,\,...p_n$, i.e.,:

$\mathbb{E}[X_T] = f(X_t,\,p_1,\,p_2,\,...p_n)$

This is, in essence, ***The Strong Law*** of asset pricing. However, the law of arbitrage supersedes the strong law when it is possible to show that:

$f(\mathbb{E}[(H_T^i)_{i \in I}]) \ne (C_{i,T})_{i \in I}$

only if/when it is possible to partake in both $H^i$ and $C_i$, such as in the assumption regarding complete markets.

However, in the absence of a complete market, or when faced with complicated pay-off scenarios, any expectation of a $\mathbb{Q}$ martingale may indeed be parametric at best (i.e., the expectation must taken through calibration).

My skepticism is perhaps best demonstrated by the following passage out of Baxter's and Rennie's *Financial Calculus* (kudos to @DaneelOlivaw for making me aware of this):

> Almost everything appeared safe to price via expectation and the
>   strong law, and only forwards and close relations seemed to have an
>   arbitrage price. Since 1973, however, and the infamous Black-Scholes
>   paper, just how wrong this is has slowly come out. Nowhere in this
>   book will we use the strong law again. […] All derivatives can be
>   built from the underlying −− arbitrage lurks everywhere.

Perhaps... but my personal, *fallible* experience tells me otherwise. While the no-arbitrage range of possible values for an equity option may be known presuming that the price of the equity is known, what is the fair value of an equity? I.e., how can we construct a replicating payoff for this equity in a way that is not a *tautology* (i.e., a thing which defines itself but nothing more)? To my knowledge, there exist no market for accounting values of assets and liabilities. More explicitly, how can we show the value of a thing, $C_t$, as follows:

$C_{i,t} = \int_t^T f(\mathbb{E}[H_{i,t}]P_t) \, dt$; $P_t := e^{-rt}$

when $C_{i,t}$ is a function of human perception regarding the unknown future values of $T$ and $H_{i,t}$, even if we take the risk-neutral expectation and short-rate as gospel?

Given that no perfect model for human behavior exists (otherwise that model would equal reality and its creator, a god), an imperfect (practical) answer to mitigating ***GIGO*** is to derive an expectation which make use of the fewest possible parameters. Fewer parameters means less calibration, which means decreased odds of over-fitting.

A thing which is descriptive of the past, present, and/or future, and which is also not highly calibrated has a better likelihood of being prescriptive than a thing which is more highly descriptive but also more highly calibrated. **Is there a model for that?** And don't say *degrees of freedom*...

Does this imply that highly-specified models (e.g., Heston) which calibrate expectations to observations are less robust? Not necessarily if the fit is not *garbage* (i.e., not spurious; i.e., it states something which is true regarding the nature of uncertainty), but in aggregate, I believe so.

I take the broad corpus of economic literature's failure to predict anything but the past as evidence.

Comment: "I take the broad corpus of economic literature's failure to predict anything but the past as evidence." I like this statement.

Comment: I particularly agree with the tautology part of your answer. And this is why there will always be a "smile problem" as Ayache puts it.

Comment: @Quantuple. Thank you. I actually haven't read Blank Swan, but I have just added it to my (growing) read list.